# Android Studio Arrangement of windows

Tags: android

How can I arrange windows in the Android Studio? 
For example, dock Android-DDMS window to the right side of the IDE.
I've found only tabbed view on the bottom or floating, both I don't like.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the numbered labels around the screen. You want the 6th tab (**6: Android**). Simply drag it to the right size.

Another way would be: Right click on the label -> Move to -> Right/Left/Top/Bottom.